# defining only portrait iphone and ipad media queries?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I've been trying to understand how to override bootstrap media queries for a little while now and I still do not understand how to disable certain media queries (do I have to manually override every element?).

My media queries are as follow:

```
/* anything > ipad */
@media only screen and (min-width: 972px) {
    .container {
        width: 960px;
    }
}

/* iPhone portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 479px) and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* iPad portrait */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation: portrait)  {

}
```

I want my site to have a 960px container on iPad + Desktop, and to load a full screen image on anything less than an iPhone. If the tablet or device is say a max width of 700px, they will get a 960px wide site with a horizontal scroll bar. I'm unsure how to this with bootstrap 3, I'm not using it with LESS.

Comment: According to this it should work but have you defined .container width earlier in your css? If so it will use that defined width for every size except for the one you have defined here. I think in Bootstrap there is a breakpoint of max-width 768px, you could use that to define another width so it wouldn't scroll.

Comment: Just customize the grid breakpoint and container sizes as necessary: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Try the customizer on getbootstrap.com.

Comment: @Christina cvrebert already mentioned that, thanks.